# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43624344 bytes)

Tags: php

Me da este error cuando recorro un for con los resultados de un sql:

```
    $datos = serialize($res);
    $html = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < count($res);$i++){                     
            $html = $html.'<form action="exportarTxartelak.php" method="post">
                <div class="row alumno">
                    <div class="col-4">'
                        .$res[$i]["NOMBRE"].'
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8" style="/*margin-bottom: 2rem; padding-left: 5px">                        
                            <input type="submit" name="word" style="margin: 0 0 0 10px" class="btn btn-primary" value="'.$lang["WORD"].'">
                            <input type="submit" name="pdf" style="margin: 0 0 0 10px" class="btn btn-primary" value="'.$lang["PDF"].'">
                            <input type="submit" name="mail" style="margin: 0 0 0 10px" class="btn btn-primary" value="'.$lang["EMAIL"].'">
                    </div>              
                </div>              
                <div class="col-12 info">
                        <textarea style="/*display: none;" name="resultado">'.base64_encode($datos).'</textarea>
                        <input  style="/*display: none;" type="text" name="USCOD" value="'.$res[$i]["USCOD"].'">
                </div>      
            </form>';       
        }
        echo $html;
```

Llega un punto en el que este for me devuelve error, exactamente en la vuelta nº19.

El for completo puede ocupar hasta 1041 resultados. Pretendo crear un listado (sin paginación) que me muestra el usuario con 3 botones.

Lo que me deja con inquietud es que he realizado loops con estos mismos datos pero mas complejos (generando un html completo) y no me han dado ningun problema.

Por ultimo si quito la `base64_encode($datos)` me lista correctamente, pero lo necesito dentro del formulario.

<sub>Nota: no puedo acceder a los archivos del servidor para editar la memoria</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema lo estás sufriendo por culpa de esta línea:

```
<textarea style="/*display: none;" name="resultado">'.base64_encode($datos).'</textarea>
```

Por cada registro que mostrarás en pantalla estás metiendo en un `<textarea>` el contenido de `$res` COMPLETO, y no ese resultado en particular.

Al estar metiendo el HTML en una variable ANTES de enviarla al navegador, ésta aumenta tanto de tamaño que sobrepasa el límite de memoria de PHP. Subir el tamaño máximo de PHP sólo retrasará el problema un poco, no lo soluciona.

Tienes la opción de corregirlo con el `serialize` dentro del bucle o bien dar salida directa al HTML sin pasar por una variable intermedia, o bien ambas (como te propongo al final).

La solución que te propongo:

```
$datos = serialize($res);
for($i = 0; $i < count($res); $i++) {                     
  echo '<form action="exportarTxartelak.php" method="post">
            <div class="row alumno">
                <div class="col-4">'
                    .$res[$i]["NOMBRE"].'
                </div>
                <div class="col-8" style="/*margin-bottom: 2rem; padding-left: 5px">                        
                        <input type="submit" name="word" style="margin: 0 0 0 10px" class="btn btn-primary" value="'.$lang["WORD"].'">
                        <input type="submit" name="pdf" style="margin: 0 0 0 10px" class="btn btn-primary" value="'.$lang["PDF"].'">
                        <input type="submit" name="mail" style="margin: 0 0 0 10px" class="btn btn-primary" value="'.$lang["EMAIL"].'">
                </div>              
            </div>              
            <div class="col-12 info">
                    <textarea style="/*display: none;" name="resultado">'.base64_encode($datos).'</textarea>
                    <input  style="/*display: none;" type="text" name="USCOD" value="'.$res[$i]["USCOD"].'">
            </div>      
        </form>';       
    }
```

Y si estoy en lo cierto y sólo quieres que aparezcan los datos serializados del registro en curso, entonces deberás hacer:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($res); $i++) {                     
  $datos = serialize($res[$i]);
  echo '<form action="exportarTxartelak.php" method="post">
            <div class="row alumno">
                <div class="col-4">'
                    .$res[$i]["NOMBRE"].'
                </div>
                <div class="col-8" style="/*margin-bottom: 2rem; padding-left: 5px">                        
                        <input type="submit" name="word" style="margin: 0 0 0 10px" class="btn btn-primary" value="'.$lang["WORD"].'">
                        <input type="submit" name="pdf" style="margin: 0 0 0 10px" class="btn btn-primary" value="'.$lang["PDF"].'">
                        <input type="submit" name="mail" style="margin: 0 0 0 10px" class="btn btn-primary" value="'.$lang["EMAIL"].'">
                </div>              
            </div>              
            <div class="col-12 info">
                    <textarea style="/*display: none;" name="resultado">'.base64_encode($datos).'</textarea>
                    <input  style="/*display: none;" type="text" name="USCOD" value="'.$res[$i]["USCOD"].'">
            </div>      
        </form>';       
    }
```

Comment: Como siempre me has vuelto ha salvar, muchas gracias no me habia dado cuenta de lo tonto del error ajajja

Comment: De nada @AndoniAlda, siempre es un placer poder ayudar :)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que corregir el `php.ini`

```
memory_limit=512M
```

Luego reiniciar el apache y listo

Comment: Veo que no has leido los comentarios con @ArturoJamaica, no puedo modificar el servidor. Añadire esos datos a la pregunta para evitar mas confusiones.

Comment: motivo la cual no tengas acceso?

Comment: Normas de la empresa

Answer (score 0):

Ocurre por que ya no tienes memoria asignada en el hosting que usas. Te dan 128 mb y ya los agotaste. Hay varias maneras de arreglar eso.

Yo primeramente liberaria $datos o $res por que por lo que veo guardan lo mismo pero serializado. Estas usando el doble de memoria para algo que quiza es lo mismo.

Por otro lado si tienes acceso puedes modificar el php.ini del servidor para que te asigne mas memoria. El campo es memory_limit

Tambien puedes hacerlo en el .httaccess agregando php_value memory_limit 256M.

La solución temporal es poner mas memoria en ese archivo ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

Comment: No se me permite modificar los archivos del servidor. Por otra parte,recorro `$res` pero necesito enviar `$datos`.

Comment: Modifica tu serializer para ir leyendo de poquito en poquito. Te va a tomar mas tiempo pero vas a optimizar tu memotia.

Comment: ok, y eso como se haria?

Comment: Sube el antes del for
    $encoded =  base64_encode($datos)

y abajo solo imprimes el $encoded